# How can I safely run untrusted Java applications?

Tags: java, security

I'm writing an autograder web application that accepts a program from the user as input. What are some ways of protecting my web server from malicious program inputs?

Currently only Java program inputs are supported. I'm thinking about somehow disabling access to certain packages/classes, but I'm not sure how.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest approach for protecting against unwanted malicious program input is to simply run it in a separate VM. If you're on Linux, boot up a VM using KVM or something, run the program there, and have the output logged somewhere (over a virtual serial port, for example). Give the VM no network access and wipe its drive each time.

Failing that, Java does have an extensive security and sandboxing model, originally designed for isolating applets. However, it's tricky to use properly, and I wouldn't recommend using it for something like this - spawning a VM is much easier and safer.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I spawn a fresh VM each time a program is run? That seems rather clunky and slow (albeit effective). Also interfacing a web application with such a VM seems difficult (though I don't have much experience with virtualization so I could be wrong). Ideally I would like the application to give instant feedback to the user.

Comment: If you save a pristine, pre-booted RAM image of the VM, you can launch it quite quickly, actually.